# Creating heavily nested python dictionaries in a clean programmatic way

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am using a series of functions to populate a heavily nested dictionary. I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this than just long assignment string as shown in the example below.

```
outputdict = {}
outputdict['x']={}
outputdict['x']['y']={}
outputdict['x']['y']['total_patients']=len(example_dict.keys())
outputdict['x']['y']['z']={}
for variable1 in variable1s:
    outputdict['x']['y']['z'][str(variable1)]={}
    outputdict['x']['y']['z'][str(variable1)]['total_patients']=function_1(example_dict, variable1).count()
    for popn in ['total','male','female']:
        outputdict['x']['y']['z'][str(variable1)][popn]={}
        for age_bucket in np.linspace(40,60,5):
            age_str = str(age_bucket)+'_'+str(age_bucket+5)
            outputdict['x']['y']['z'][str(variable1)][popn][age_str]={}
            outputdict['x']['y']['z'][str(variable1)][popn]["total"]={}
            for res in restypes:
                if popn == 'total':
                    codelist, ncodes = function_2(function_1(example_dict, variable1), res, age_bucket)
                else:
                    codelist, ncodes = function_2_gender(function_1(example_dict, variable1), res, age_bucket, popn)
                outputdict['x']['y']['z'][str(variable1)][popn][age_str][res]={}
                outputdict['x']['y']['z'][str(variable1)][popn][age_str][res]['total_codes']=ncodes
                outputdict['x']['y']['z'][str(variable1)][popn][age_str][res]['top_codes']=[]
                for item in codelist:
                    disp = {"code": item[0][:2], "value":item[0][2], "count":item[1]}

                    outputdict['x']['y']['z'][str(variable1)][popn][age_str][res]['top_codes'].append(disp)


                codelist, ncodes = list_top_codes(function_1(example_dict, variable1), res)
                outputdict['x']['y']['z'][str(variable1)][popn]["total"][res]={}
                outputdict['x']['y']['z'][str(variable1)][popn]["total"][res]['top_codes']=[]
                for item in codelist:
                    disp = {"code": item[0][:2], "value":item[0][2], "count":item[1]}
                    outputdict['x']['y']['z'][str(variable1)][popn]["total"][res]['top_codes'].append(disp)
outputdict
```

Comment: [`from collections import defaultdict; outputdict = defaultdict(dict)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: Why is your data structure so absurdly nested? It probably doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [autovivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification#Python) with [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). This would allow you to skip the creation of empty dicts since they would be automatically created when undefined key is dereferenced:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = lambda: defaultdict(dd)

d = dd()
d['foo']['bar']['foobar'] = 1
```

So your code would look like following:

```
outputdict = dd()
outputdict['x']['y']['total_patients']=len(example_dict.keys())

for variable1 in variable1s:
    outputdict['x']['y']['z'][str(variable1)]['total_patients']=function_1(example_dict, variable1).count()
```

The other possible improvement would be storing the nested dictionary to variable so that you wouldn't have to type the full path everywhere:

```
for variable1 in variable1s:
    nested = dd()
    outputdict['x']['y']['z'][str(variable1)]=nested
    nested['total_patients']=function_1(example_dict, variable1).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid dictionary initializations by using a defaultdict of a dict. 
You can chain these as far as you want to make a nested dictionary hierarchy. For instance, here is a 2 and 3 level hierarchy dictionary.

```
two_level = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
three_level = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict)))
```

Your dictionary is now as follows: `two_level[1][2]` and `three_level[1][2][3]` and will be empty dicts `{}`.

So in your case, it appears you have a 4 level nesting, so I'd probably initialize outputdict as:

```
output_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))))
```

Can't think of anything else you can do here - I'd recommend that you simplify this nested structure, if possible.